# Other methods to unbrick LG X210 from other identical phone?

Tags: unbricking, lg

Recently I accidentally formatted my preloader on my LG X210 smartphone, which is an MTK device (MT6580).
Because of this my phone doesn't react when I press the power button, and the screen remains black when plugging it in to charge etc. I guess that's what they call hard-bricking a phone. (and yes, I checked that my battery was still 80% full)

Because it's an MTK device it is still possible to flash the stock ROM by going into meta mode (first install the necessary drivers and then remove battery from phone, keep volume up pressed in and simultaneously insert USB cable connected to computer). I used the flash tool (SP_Flash_Tool_v5.1532_Win) to first format the rom:

[image: flash formatting]

Then I downloaded the stock ROM (MT6580__lge__LG-X210__m13g__5.1__ALPS.L1.MP6.V2.19_ARIMA6580.WE.L_P42), which looks like this when extracted:

[image: stock rom contents]

So all I still had to do was:

1. Flash only the preloader
2. Then unplug the phone /plug back in again
3. Finally flash the rest (see picture:)

[image: flash details]

I searched online and this method seemed to work for a lot of users; i.e. they would then unplug their phone and the device would be able to power up etc.
However, in my case it still doesn't... I am very sure that this is the correct stock ROM that I used.

Does anyone know what else I could try to do?
Note that I have a second identical LG X210 phone which is still working fine (but it's not mine) - perhaps there is a way to dump the rom and restore it in my phone? (assuming the stock rom itself has a fault in its preloader)

Comment: Does the phone get detected in the device manager? You can unbrick it with SP Flashtool

Comment: Yes the device gets detected in the device manager, and the screenshots are made in SP Flashtool; but I seem to think that the stock rom is incorrect: even if I flash the preloader with SP Flash tool, the device won't interact at all if I normally charge it or keep the power button pressed in. I have a second phone though - but I don't know how to extract the preloader from it

Comment: You'll need to know the address and length of the preloader. Or check for Tools such as Miracle Box (paid) or NCK Box (paid), or their cracked version which may be harmful to your computer for viruses ( some are false positive alerts though)

Comment: The ReadBack tab on SP Flashtool is for dumbing then you cab flash it back

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this YouTube video may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3TmXtOA0IA.

My i-mobile i-STYLE 712 (MT6580) did react only to show the battery, but after you plug it in, it asks for a signal for 1 or 2 seconds only. In the first two seconds, you have to send the correct signal to hold it in the USB contact. You can't see it, but you can prove it with `usbdeview-x64.zip` for example. Then you need `SP_Flash_Tool_v5.1804_Win.zip` and the MTK USB drivers.

It was dead, but I got it back to work. The links in the YouTube video may be outdated but the information was very helpful for me, I did try to flash a custom TWRP, but it wasn't for this device and kill the preloader too.